# Is there a standard C++ class that is like QByteArray?

Tags: c++, qt, stl

Is there a STL C++ class that works like [QByteArray](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qbytearray.html#details)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
std::string
```

or

```
std::vector<unsigned char>
```

Comment: std::string is not capable of holding data containing \0. It will stop at first occurence, so yes... std::vector would be best replacement

Comment: @Kamil: -1 for that comment. It is entirely capable. For instance, `std::string(10, '\0')` is a string with ten \0 characters.

Answer (score 2):

A complete replacement, no.  Depending on what you are using it for, std::vector may suffice well enough as a replacement.